# angular js in ng-reapeat display value name .extension after not display

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I want to use `ng-repeat` in value display but `.extension` do not display.

my code below:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, doc) in documentdetails.Root[0].Record">
    <td>
       <a class="link" target="_blank" href="../admin/views/documents/{{doc}}">{{ doc }}</a>
   </td>
```

{{ doc }} in i get `abc.pdf` which is pdf file's name, but i want to display only `abc` without `.extension`.

how can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

try use `split`

```
 <td>
   <a class="link" target="_blank" 
      href="../admin/views/documents/{{doc.split('\.')[0]}}">{{ doc }}</a>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("controller", function($scope) {
  $scope.doc = "abc.pdf";
})
app.filter('filename', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input.split(".")[0];
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  {{doc|filename}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a simple split function in view and dont apply that on href as below

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.documentdetails = {"Root":[{"Record":["documents.php","OSHA_lockout_regulation.pdf","LOTO_Matrix_2016.docx","LOTO_Log_2016.pdf","Sample_LOTO_policy.pdf","iLockitOut_Help.pdf","Employee_Training.pdf"]}]};
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, doc) in documentdetails.Root[0].Record">
    <td>
        <a class="link" target="_blank" href="../admin/views/documents/{{doc}}" >{{ doc.split('\.')[0] }}</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```